# Internal Linking within EE Controlpanel

Tags: wysiwyg

Is it possible to somehow set internal links in the rich text editor (Or any other wysiwyg field). Instead of copying the links from the adressbar? Maybe with a dropdown?

Thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an add-on called wygwam entries http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam-entries for P&T's wygwam which does exactly that.
On github you'll find another wygwam one that can link to structure pages: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/wygwam_structure_pages